# awk or sed to delete a pattern with string and number

Tags: awk

I have a file with the following content:

```
string1_204
string2_408
string35_592
```

I need to get rid of string1_,string2_,string35_ and so on and add 204,408,592 to get a value.
so the output should be 1204.

I can take out string1_ and string 2_ but for string35_592 I have 5_592.
I cant seem to get the command right to do what I want to do. Please any help is appreciated:)

Answer (score 5):

With awk:

```
awk -F_ '{s+=$2}END{print s}' your.txt
```

Output:

```
1204
```

Explanation:

```
-F_    sets the field separator to _ what makes it easy to access
       the numbers later on

{
    # runs on every line of the input file
    # adds the value of the second field - the number - to s.
    # awk auto initializes s with 0 on it's first usage
    s+=$2
}
END {
    # runs after all input has been processed
    # prints the sum
    print s
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you are interested in a coreutils/bc alternative:

```
<infile cut -d_ -f2 | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

Output:

```
1024
```

#### Explanation:

`cut` splits each line at underscore characters (`-d_`) and outputs only the second field (`-f2`). The column of numbers is passed on to `paste` which joins them on a line (`-s`) delimited by plus characters (`-d+`). This is passed on to `bc` which calculates and outputs the sum.

Comment: rather cryptic, but now I know that `<infile` can be in front of the line

Comment: @newtover: I find it more readable and easier to edit this way.